# Проверка наличия файла во внешнем ресурсе

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Как выполнить проверку наличия файла во внешнем ресурсе при запуске той или ной активити? 
Возможно, решение это попытаться прочитать и в FileNotFoundExeption вписать код, но Android Studio почему-то ругается на то что исключение FileNotFound уже отловлено, хотя стоит лишь IOExpection. 
Вопрос: как решить проблему с исключениями, либо предложите вариант получше для решения проблемы.

Comment: `FileNotFoundExeption` расширяет `IOException`, так что никакого "стоит лишь `IOException`": `FileNotFoundExeption` вполне себе ловится в блоке `catch (IOException e)`. Поставьте блок `catch (FileNotFoundExeption e)` до `catch (IOException e)`.

Comment: @Regent Секундочку, сейчас я попробую

Comment: @Regent с исключениями всё в порядке, но чёт падает. Ладно, всё равно спасибо.

Comment: Почему бы просто не проверять на isExist() файл после создания new File(String path)

Comment: @A-Z а вот с этого момента поподробнее. Можете привести пример использования этих методов? Просто до этого момента я не знал об их сущевствовании.

Comment: В документации java , класс File содержит метод exists(), который показывает существует ли файл или нет. Его можно вызвать после создания нового объекта (new File(String filePath)), ну вот, собственно и всё - проверку делать.  if(yourFile.exists())//do what you need

Comment: @A-Z спасибо, попробую